# Spotbugs sequential execution as gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, spotbugs

I have a problem with running spotbugs as sequential gradle task.
I want to mentioned that the project is Java multi module based.
I am running parallel gradle tasks at once(up to 8 like compile,test,…) on different modules and I do not want to change that behavior.
What I want is just one gradle task, in my case that task is spotbugs to run sequentially and the other tasks to run in parallel.
Does gradle provides some option for that?

**UPDATE**:
Use the Gradle feature called BuildService :)
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_services.html

Comment: What's the purpose of limiting SpotBugs tasks in sequential?

Comment: @chehsunliu SpotBugs task require a lot of resources, like 1GB of RAM. I don't have control which task will be executed at time and if gradle run more than 4 or 5 parallel Spotbugs tasks, my machine starting lock files for no reason and to fix that I need to restart the machine, nothing else helps even if you try to kill the process...
So that is the reason why I want only this task to run sequential :)

Comment: A workaround would be assigning cross-project task dependencies among all the SpotBugs tasks explicitly. But the gradle script might look ugly and not easy to maintain.

In my case, I do not run SpotBugs locally. I only run it on GitHub Actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you create a [shared build service](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_services.html). This build service does not need to have any parameters and does not need to have any actual logic, it is only used for the sequencialising. You configure this build service to be used by maximum one task. And then you define all the tasks you want non-parallel to each other to use that service. This will cause only one of those tasks to run at the same time.